# Do I really need the div class entry?

Tags: theme-development, themes, pages, page-template

I was wondering if it's really neccessary to keep the `<div class="entry">` in the page.php file (or any other template for that matter). I typically use a blank HTML5 wordpress theme and it doesn't have any declarations within the CSS file for that class.

So I just wanted to get other opinions on it. Thanks!

Comment: I guess it would depend on what CSS is declared for that class, and if you plan on using it for your theme.

Comment: As far as I remember correctly, `entry` and it's child classes were initiated for support of hAtom/hentry microformats. Nowadays schema.org seems to be the most important enriching data scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No specific markup is required in a theme. The only exception are themes published on wordpress.org, they have to follow the [guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review). And even there, `<div class="entry">` is not required.

The only parts you have to use are these:

```
while ( have_posts() )
{
    the_post();
    print '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    the_content();
    wp_link_pages();
}
```

Comment: Shaboom. Thanks! Yeah, I kinda figured, but I just wanted to make sure that I was keeping things consistent and semantic. But that puts it into perspective. Thanks again!

Comment: @ultraloveninja See my [Mini Theme](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme) for a complete example. :)